# How to Kill All Threads Created by the Current Class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to web programming, and I've created a server class that forks off `ClientProcess` threads to service each client's connection. Currently I have 2 problems:

1. Keeping track of running threads
2. **Shutting down the threads once execution finishes and closing connections** (the topic of this thread)

For problem one, I'm currently using an `Arraylist<ClientProcess>` to hold a list of threads and call `Thread.interrupt()` at the appropriate time. I know that the java API contains a class `ThreadGroup` that is supposed to perform this task but I don't know how I'm supposed to add threads to the group or if that just happens automatically when I call `Thread.start()`. In other words, I have already solved this problem but if anyone knows a better way to perform this I'm open to implement one.

For problem two, I still have no clue how to begin. I've read the article about [Thread.stop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) by Oracle but I don't understand their recommendation for how to interrupt/stop the thread. For reference, my `ClientProcess` class looks something like this:

```java
public class ClientProcess extends Thread {
    private Socket clientConnection;

    /* class constructor, etc. */

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(clientConnection.getInputStream());
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream())) {
             while (in.hasNext()) { /* do stuff */ }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             /* close connection, clean resources, etc. */
        }
    }
}
```

From the article, it looks like I'm supposed to be storing a reference to the thread in the class (why?) and that I'm supposed to set the variable to null when I want to stop the thread from running, then check for null anywhere that the thread may stop. I don't see a reason for my thread to hold a reference to itself or to have to check if it's `null` with every single branch statement that I need to perform in `run()`. I'm open to a complete refactor of the code (this project is still in its early stages) but I'm just looking for anyone to point me in the right direction.

Edit: The question already has a few answers, but I realized that my real question is very different than what I asked. I'm trying to learn modern techniques for web programming, and I remembered that a few years ago I read in a C++ web programming book that multithreading is typically used in order to service clients. After poking around a bit on the web I've seen that web programming has evolved to fit demand and now uses completely different paradigms. What I really should have asked was something along the lines of 'How do I Create a Server that can Handle Taskes Asynchronously' or 'What are some Modern Programming Paradigms for Server/Client Architectures?' The real answer to this question is that multithreading is no longer considered tractable and that there are other paradigms that I should be using to solve this problem.

Comment: You really shouldn't depend on Thread.stop. You should separate your 'threads' from your task. It's a good idea to use an ExecutorService to handle your threads. Then just write tasks. Also, the tasks should know how to end themselves. That might mean you need to keep a reference to your objects or check for interrupted in your run method. Also, did you really write an applet? They are way outdated.

Comment: Do java developers still use raw threads and thread.kill? seriously? it's 2020, move along.

Comment: I'm not a java developer, my question mentions that I'm completely new to web programming and multithreading. If you have a suggestion for what API to use, I will gladly switch to it.

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct.  FYI.

Comment: @Gray--SOstopbeingevil why isn't it correct? because of the edit with all of 'c++ threads are bad bits?'

Comment: Some info, before I decided to change my implementation, I did end up using an `ExecutorService` to perform multithreading and Matt's solution worked just fine for me. Could you clarify why it's incorrect?

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a caught exception meaning that only those methods that advertise that they throw it will do so.  In the case of blocking IO methods, most likely they do not throw `InterruptedException`.  That means that even though you call `shutdownNow()`, the threads will not finish until the IO call completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make blocking calls that throw an interrupt exception, then interrupting the thread will cause an interrupt exception. Otherwise, you'll have to explicitly check if the thread has been interrupted. You should have an executor service for starting your class.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

Then submit tasks:

```
Future<?> f = executor.submit( ()->{
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(clientConnection.getInputStream());
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream())) {
         while (in.hasNext()) { /* do stuff */ }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //try with resources takes care of the streams. 
        return;
    }
} );
```

Then when you need to shutdown all you have to do is.

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

Then your currently running tasks will be interrupted. There are execution services with more features to, and you can use the futures to control the task.

Comment: None of those methods throw `InterruptedException` unless you are using some of the NIO interruptable channels.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Keeping track of running threads
>
> I know that the java API contains a class ThreadGroup that is supposed to perform this task but I don't know how I'm supposed to add threads to the group

Yeah, using your own collection of threads, or even better an [`ExecutorService`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html), to manage your threads is the right thing to do.  I've written a large number of Java threaded applications and never had to use a `ThreadGroup`.

> 2) Shutting down the threads once execution finishes and closing connections

Unfortunately, you cannot use `thread.interrupt()` to cause an IO method to throw `InterruptedException` because none of the IO methods throw that exception unless you are using NIO's `InterruptibleChannel` or other special classes.  If you are interrupting a thread that is processing something, you can test for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` but not when you are blocking on IO.

The right thing to do here would be to close the client socket out from under it.  I would add a `clientProcess.close()` method which closes the `Socket clientConnection`.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
   clientConnection.close();
}
```

This will then cause the client thread which is reading on that socket to get an `IOException` when it goes to read from the socket which it can catch and return to stop running.

> From the article, it looks like I'm supposed to be storing a reference to the thread in the class (why?) and that I'm supposed to set the variable to null when I want to stop the thread from running

If your thread is looping around, it is common to use a `volatile` field which could be set by the caller to cause the looping thread to stop.  But in your case, the thread is waiting on IO and not in a processing loop so I think closing the socket is the way to go.

---

Comment: "Unfortunately, you cannot use thread.interrupt() unless the specific method throws"  That is not true, Thread.interrupted, or Thread.isInterrupted can be used to see if your task should be interrupted. You can write you task such that it checks if the thread has been interrupted and then modify the accordingly. Even throwing an InterruptedException.